# Email attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to attach a file that I generate (on the fly, I dont want to save the file on my server) and send it out via email.

I have the text all done, but I'm lost on how to attach the file to the email using sendmail

Thank you

Answer (score 21):

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

```
def registration_confirmation(user)
  @user = user
  attachments["rails.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png")
  mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered")
end
```

Comment: But if you are sending diffrent file format like csv, xls etc., then you should also mention the body part otherwise the attachment is not send properly in the mail

Comment: it would be nice if you accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 6):

You should be using Action Mailer that's built into Rails which supports sending emails with attachments.

For Rails 3.x - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments

For Rails 2.3.8+ - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails-with-attachments

Answer (score 1):

For alternative consideration, I personally have had a good experience using [Pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony) for email. It happens to have a lot of gem dependencies, but it is very nice to work with. See the [README](https://github.com/benprew/pony#readme) for more information.