# Attachment not sent properly in rails using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am trying to send xls file via ActionMailer.

```
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(:to => "reciever@gmail.com", :from => "sender@gmail.com", :content_type=>"application/vnd.ms-excel", :body=> '')
mailer.attachments['filename.xls']= {mime_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', content: File.read("filePath.xls")}
mailer.deliver!
```

I am able to receive the mail as well.
But somehow the attachment is not correct, it shows up as noname and below is the content I get in the file (I am copy pasting the exact contents)

--

```
Date: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 23:33:48 +0530
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename=filename.xls
Content-ID: <538f5f82836992@C02L2178FFT3.gmail>

PGgzIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXdlaWdodDpib2xkIj4gCiAgICBTaG93aW5nCiAg
ICBvcGVuCiAgICByZXF1ZXN0cwogICAgZnJvbQogICAgTm92IDIxLCAyMDEz
....
```

I am sure I am missing something simple, I am unable to figure out what. Can someone help?

Comment: This might help you to get the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610689/email-attachments#comment42373470_4610864

Answer (score 1):

Try this:--

```
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(:to => "reciever@gmail.com", :from => "sender@gmail.com", :content_type=>"application/vnd.ms-excel", :body=> '')
mailer.attachments["filename.xls"]= File.read("filePath.xls")
mailer.deliver!
```